# vb.net DataGridView Not Reloading Correctly

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have some text boxes that I insert data into a table/datagridview. I have a search box, and editing capability in the datagridview.

When I do not insert data into the table with the below code everything works (edit, search, delete etc.) If I do insert data then the search and edits do not work.

Is there something wrong with the below?

```
 Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT res_inv, res_snbr, First_Name, Last_Name, Item, Inventory_Start_Date, Inventory_End_Date FROM Resident_InventoryLists2", cn)


Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adap)
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim res_snbr As Object




Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CIInventoryDataSet.CurrentRoom_InventoryList' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CurrentRoom_InventoryListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CIInventoryDataSet.CurrentRoom_InventoryList)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CIInventoryDataSet.Resident_InventoryLists2' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Resident_InventoryLists2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.CIInventoryDataSet.Resident_InventoryLists2)

    DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
    '
    adap.Fill(dt)
    '   ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource.DataSource = dt
    ResidentInventoryLists2BindingSource.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = CurrentRoomInventoryListBindingSource
End Sub



Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        CurrentRoomInventoryListBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("res_last_name Like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
        '  ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("res_last_name like '{0}*' Or res_snbr = '{0}'", TextBox1.Text)
    Else
        CurrentRoomInventoryListBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If




End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Try
        adap.Update(dt)
        MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error updating database")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Me.rnum.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    Me.rlastname.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    Me.rfname.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    Me.txtbed.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value






End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    cn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("Insert INTO Resident_InventoryLists2 Values('" & _
                              rnum.Text & "','" & _
                              rfname.Text & "','" & _
                              rlastname.Text & "','" & _
                              txtitem.Text & "','" & _
                              StartDate.Text & "','" & _
                              EndDate.Text & "','" & _
                              txtCompany.Text & "')"), cn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()






    rnum.Clear()
    rfname.Clear()
    rlastname.Clear()
    rnum.Clear()
    txtitem.Clear()
    StartDate.Clear()

    adap.Fill(dt)

    Me.Resident_InventoryLists2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.CIInventoryDataSet.Resident_InventoryLists2)

End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If TextBox2.TextLength > 0 Then
        '  ResidentInventoryLists2BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Last_Name Like '%{0}%'" Or "item like '%{0}%'", TextBox2.Text)
        ResidentInventoryLists2BindingSource.Filter = String.Format("Last_Name like '{0}*'", TextBox2.Text)

    Else
        ResidentInventoryLists2BindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.SelectedRows
        DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: A) use SQL parameters; you could be changing datatypes with StartDate for example  B) You should probably specify the column names in the SQL  so that each bit of data maps to the correct column

Comment: Can you give an Example of this: You should probably specify the column names in the SQL so that each bit of data maps to the correct column. Do you mean :  rnum.Text & "MyColumnName," & _

Comment: Also my table in SQL is all varchar even for dates

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm  `my table in SQL is all text even for dates` if you want your dates to act like dates, dont do that

Comment: well all the data is inserting into the table. That doesnt seem to be the issue. The issue is once the data inserted into the table - I am unable to edit /delete/search etc) If data is already in the table/datagrid I can editit/delete/search etc. I figured that it has something to do with these two lines of code: adap.Fill(dt)

        Me.Resident_InventoryLists2TableAdapter.Fill(Me.CIInventoryDataSet.Resident_InventoryLists2)

Comment: then show *that* code...the code that *doesnt* work.  (What is there now, still has a number of issues).

Comment: I reposted - the whole project. I thought that it is only where i insert data because After I insert data into the 2nd datagridview I have on screen, my edit, delete does not work. Please let me know if this makes sense.